# Check if an Object has something or not

Tags: c#

I have the following property:

```
IDictionary<string, object> Values { get; }
```

The property has a few values having one of them the key "culture".

I tried to use that value and casting to a string:

```
String value = (String)data.Values["culture"] ?? defaultCulture;
```

This works when the item has some value but when it doesn't I get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter' to type 'System.String'.
```

BTW, System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlparameter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

**In the debugger data.Values["culture"] has the value {}**. I tested and:

```
var test_1 = data.Values["culture"] == null; // returns false

var test_2 = data.Values["culture"].ToString() == null; // returns false
```

How do I check if data.Values["culture"] has something in it or not?

Comment: [IDictionary has a Contains method for checking if a key exists.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.contains.aspx)

Comment: Yes, the key exists ... but the value is {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you are storing a `UrlParameter` in that dictionary entry. If you want to get a string out, you will need to use `ToString()`.

The exact expression to use will depend on the type of `defaultCulture`. If it is a string, then

```
String value = data.Values["culture"] == null ? defaultCulture : data.Values["culture"].ToString();
```

if it is a UrlParameter, then

```
String value = (data.Values["culture"] ?? defaultCulture).ToString();
```

Comment: [`UrlParameter.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlparameter.tostring.aspx) returns an empty string.

Comment: defaultValue is a string but your code does not work ... data.Values["culture"] == null returns false ... because data.Values["culture"] is {} (checked in the debugger). I never get it null. That was my initial problem. I don't know how to test it against {}

Comment: Did you try my code? It would execute the `data.Values["culture"].ToString()` branch.

Comment: John, the problem is before that ... Please, read my question. I just updated it. The problem is when the value is empty I do not get null for data.Values["culture"] ... what I get in the debugger is ... so data.Values["culture"] == null returns false.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, so when it's not null, then `data.Values["culture"].ToString()` will work in that case.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I want to also have the value defaultCulture. What I was trying to understand is what is an object with {}. It is not null but at the same time has nothing in it ... So how to check it?

Comment: I'm not an MVC expert, but looking at the documentation of the `UrlParameter` class, I think you're seeing `UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: Yes, you are right ... instead of comparing to null I compare it to UrlParameter.Optional

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `string` if it indeed is a string and a default value otherwise, you can test the type of the valuer using `as`. Something like:

```
(data.Values["culture"] as string) ?? defaultCulture
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String value = (String) (data.Values["culture"] ?? defaultCulture);
```

The idea is to check for null before trying to cast.

Comment: Again, I never get data.Values["culture"] as null ... It has always a value (string) or {} ... And is {} which I am not sure how to check ... It is not null but it has nothing in it ...

Answer (score 0):

did you use this?

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(somestring)
```

Comment: You mean String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.Values["culture"].ToString());? Why convert it to string and do the test after it? I mean, how to test an object which value in the debugger is {} ... What is this? null it is not because I checked.